# What's the difference between a Higher One and a Great One?

Tags: russian-language, sergei-lukyanenko, night-watch-cycle

In Sergei Lukyanenko's *Watch* series, there are several different "grades" of magical power, from seventh-grade all the way up to first-grade and then beyond. As I understand it, everyone above first-grade power is called a Higher Magician (or Higher Vampire, etc.): they are **"Higher Ones"**.

But another title I've seen used now and then is **"Great One"**. Gesar and Zabulon are sometimes addressed or referred to as Great Ones, and I think so is Foma/Thomas the Rhymer in Edinburgh, Rustam in Uzbekistan, and a very few others. But when

> Anton becomes a Higher One

at the end of *Twilight Watch*, nobody in *Last Watch* ever refers to him as "Great One".

**What is the difference between a Higher One and a Great One?** Is "Great One" a loosely defined term of respect for extremely experienced and high-ranking Higher Ones? Does it mean something not directly related to magical power? (Do the original Russian terms make anything clearer?)

Comment: Can you please provide exact quote and location for calling "Great One"? I'm not sure it's not just an artefact of translation. My version of Russian Night Watch explicitly states "Великие маги и волшебницы уходят за пределы человеческих эмоций. Наверное, они испытывают какие-то свои, вот только нам их не понять. Даже Гесер, маг вне классификации, не Великий. Ольга так и не смогла стать Великой." - meaning that Geser wasn't "Great", neither was Olga (this was in context of discussing Svetlana's future)

Comment: Another issue - there's also a random use of the term "great" with lower case G, e.g. in the same Night Watch, Geser and Zavulon are described as lower-g "great": "Но есть цель, что оправдывает средства. Два великих мага, сотни лет противостоящих друг другу, затевают очередную маленькую войну."

Comment: And just for s and giggles, he contradicts himself in the same Night Watch, stating that Olga was a **former** Great one: "Она выдавливала слова, будто ей сдавило горло. Не верю! Не бывает стыда у Светлых магов, проживших тысячи лет. Они спасали мир так часто, что знают все этические отговорки назубок. Не бывает стыдно Великим Волшебницам, пусть даже бывшим. Их самих предавали слишком часто. Я засмеялся."

Comment: And Day watch calls Geser Great :(

Comment: @DVK I don't have the books to hand right now, but I'll try to remember to check tonight. Have a look in *Last Watch* (#4) - I'm pretty sure Gesar and a few others are called Great Ones there. (Maybe this question is even more interesting than I'd thought, if it uncovers contradictions in the books!)

Comment: @DVK OK, I combed through the text of *Last Watch* (no searchable ebooks for me) and found at least two instances of "Great One": when Anton meets Rustam (*"So you are Rustam after all," I said, bowing my head. "Greetings, Great One! Thank you for responding to our request."*) and Merlin (*"I greet you, Great One," I said, bowing my head. "It is an honour for me ... to see the Great Merlin.") I couldn't find anything for Gesar or Zabulon offhand, but past tales suggest Gesar and Rustam were roughly equal to each other?

Comment: SPOILER ALERT for #6 --------- Anton is referred to as Great One in Book 6.

Comment: As far as "higher"  is concerned, it was more liberal - one didn't need to get all that far to be higher vampire, 2nd level was enough.

Comment: @Mithoron Do you have a quote to confirm that? I remember "Higher One" being used only for those above first grade; it's been a long time now since I read the books, but that's also what I wrote here.